# Maximize value of exponential

Tags: stochastic-processes

How can i go about maximising the value of the following,

$$
exp\left( -\alpha e^{rT}x -\alpha\sigma\lambda e^{rT}\int_0^T e^{-rs}\pi_sds+\frac{1}{2}(\alpha\sigma)^2 e^{2rT}\int_0^Te^{-2rs}\pi_s^2ds \right) 
$$

with respect to the process $(\pi_s)_{s>0}$?

Am tempted to differentiate with respect to $\pi_s$, but also not quite sure what's the right way to do that

Comment: What is $\pi_s$?  Is it an arbitrary function of $s$?

Comment: $\pi_s$ is a process dependent on $s$. I've update the question to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

Complete the squares:
$$\frac{1}{2}(\alpha\sigma)^2 e^{2rT}\int_0^Te^{-2rs}\pi_s^2ds-\alpha\sigma\lambda e^{rT}\int_0^T e^{-rs}\pi_sds=\frac 12\int_0^T\left(e^{r(t-s)} \pi_s\alpha \sigma  +\lambda \right)^2\mathrm ds -\frac{T\lambda^2}2 .$$